# SQL query WHERE filter exclusive

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to do some simple filter in sql but didn't get success.

```
table1
id  table2Id table3Id name    value
1   null     1        test0   null
2   null     2        test2   null    <== i want exclude this line from my result
3   1        2        test2   MOB
```

I want to exclude from result when the condition is `table2Id = null and table3Id = 2`,
but the condition fails in the first one.

i'm doing:

```
SELECT NAME,VALUE FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT(table2Id = null AND table3Id = 2)
```

and getting:

```
table1
id  table2Id table3Id name    value
3   1        2        test2   MOB
```

I want:

```
id  table2Id table3Id name    value
3   1        2        test2   MOB
1   null     1        test0   null
```

Comment: `table2Id is null` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: damn, worked... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

```
SELECT NAME,
       VALUE 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE NOT(table2Id IS null AND table3Id = 2)
```